# Django: What's the best field type to represent time elapsed?

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm need to save the time that some task took to the user to finish it.

For example, suppose you have to answer a couple of questions of an exam. If you started at 10:00 am and finish it at 11:00am I'd like to store the time it took you to finish it. In this case it'd be 1hr or 60 minutes, or 3600 seconds.

After that i'd like to display that in a pretty way. Suppose something took 527 seconds, i'd like to show: 8'47. So i'd need some template tag to do the work.

Of course i've seen `TimeField`, but it's using datetime.time, and I don't think it's the rigth fit for this situation.

I've also analized using just an `IntegerField` storing seconds (that level of detail is Ok). But maybe you guys know a better option.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

An integral field storing seconds is probably best for storing durations (it's easy to then plug that into a `timedelta`). Of course, if you think you might want to store fractions of a second in the future, you  might want to consider making it a float field instead.

You could also subclass either `IntegerField` or `FloatField` and make a version that automatically translates the contents to and from a `timedelta` automatically... [or use one that someone's created already](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1060/).